# How to find top 10 scored nodes from a dictionary

Tags: python, social-networking

I have managed to find 4039 nodes's score.But I need to sort out/print out only top 10 node(according to highest scores).

```
def between_parallel(G, processes = None):
    p = Pool(processes=processes)
    part_generator = 4*len(p._pool)
    node_partitions = list(partitions(G.nodes(), int(len(G)/part_generator)))
    num_partitions = len(node_partitions)
 
    bet_map = p.map(btwn_pool,
                        zip([G]*num_partitions,
                        [True]*num_partitions,
                        [None]*num_partitions,
                        node_partitions))
 
    bt_c = bet_map[0]
    for bt in bet_map[1:]:
        for n in bt:
            bt_c[n] += bt[n]
    return bt_c
bt = between_parallel(G_fb)

print (bt)
```

Output:

{0: 0.1463059214744286, 1: 2.7832744209034606e-06, 2: 7.595021178512074e-08, 3: 1.6850656559280464e-06, 4: 1.8403320547933104e-07, 5: 2.205964164092193e-06, 6: 2.4537760730577472e-08, 7: 0.0001702984836730361, 8: 2.7604980821899654e-07, 9: 1.6454236303026905e-05, 10: 4.986739552037655e-08, 11: 0.0, 12: 0.0, 13: 1.7622717578436846e-06, 14: 5.582871686568508e-07, 15: 0.0, 16: 1.9979459275532697e-07, 17: 4.1066669000480344e-07, 18: 0.0, 19: 5.062957964075819e-06, 20: 6.793693332142838e-07, 21: 0.0009380243844653207, 22: 6.703002200833232e-07, 23: 6.860348937590618e-06, 24: 1.3673472422981514e-07, 25: 5.38808313945586e-05, 26: 1.935436798204632e-05, 27: 3.067220091322184e-08, 28: 3.812160659244892e-07, 29: 1.3954817951917517e-06, 30: 1.3694627409316544e-06, 31: 4.932641252790837e-06, 32: 0.0, 33: 0.0, 34: 0.0036020881281963106, 35: 0.0, 36: 2.726417858953052e-08, 37: 0.0, 38: 7.344481172858835e-07, 39: 9.548632622274015e-07, 40: 1.3796059569123122e-05, 41: 4.673274954378314e-06, 42: 0.0, 43: 0.0, 44: 0.0, 45: 3.0243457405507097e-07, 46: 0.0, 47: 0.0, 48: 5.29085361854899e-06, 49: 1.8403320547933104e-07, 50: 5.135467952242277e-07, 51: 9.201660273966552e-08, 52: 0.0, 53: 1.0849233385514972e-05, 54: 3.6120168027808387e-07, 55: 1.8160988132495756e-07, 56: 0.0010850657064421774, 57: 1.5359027152243021e-06, 58: 0.08436020590796543, 59: 7.274796871349583e-07, 60: 7.546141619678459e-08, 61: 6.134440182644368e-08, 62: 2.8660815656610625e-06, 63: 0.0, 64: 1.2821395685548659e-05, 65: 6.893923913652614e-07, 66: 9.542251505382869e-08, 67: 0.0009118520705882034, 68: 1.4722656438346484e-07, 69: 1.9840927984607338e-07, 70: 0.0, 71: 0.0, 72: 1.8125106130858043e-06, 73: 6.016664242341218e-07, 74: 0.0, 75: 2.5490958649817383e-07, 76: 0.0, 77: 2.556016742768486e-07, 78: 0.0, 79: 2.0870669696912043e-08, 80: 0.0001596017223936386, 81: 6.134440182644368e-08, 82: 7.3592283705503054e-06, 83: 9.201660273966552e-08, 84: 1.3929533620512854e-06, 85: 5.032627527050142e-07, 86: 0.0, 87: 4.625863702493754e-05, 88: 4.549846123020853e-06, 89: 3.312597698627958e-07, 90: 0.0, 91: 2.7604980821899654e-07, 92: 6.842999005760918e-07, 93: 9.40614161338803e-08, 94: 2.1380836623092413e-06, 95: 6.134440182644368e-08, 96: 7.835986401270893e-07, 97: 4.089626788429578e-08, 98: 6.75276474687329e-06, 99: 8.161726604908745e-07, 100: 5.316514824958451e-07, 101: 7.890545400009306e-07, 102: 0.0, 103: 9.419040787733043e-05, 104: 3.0155346005494676e-06, 105: 4.083494447761187e-07, 106: 3.6387941210384125e-07, 107: 0.48051807855601425, 108: 3.481582493846834e-07, 109: 5.787658323854831e-06, 110: 0.0, 111: 1.5294230468062708e-06, 112: 0.0, 113: 5.229334396770685e-06, 114: 0.0, 115: 3.3336831770046665e-06, 116: 1.155762168033134e-06, 117: 2.095933729070159e-07, 118: 5.694459451841912e-06, 119: 0.0015229358857942355, 120: 4.473603006040869e-05, 121: 1.0410849313922507e-06, 122: 0.0007457760472155037, 123: 4.922689779281791e-07, 124: 1.6358507153718312e-07, 125: 8.236283906591862e-06, 126: 1.686971050227201e-07, 127: 6.370611703673157e-07, 128: 2.4337383726394154e-06, 129: 4.498589467272537e-08, 130: 2.527390717096562e-06, 131: 0.0, 132: 1.983731020051308e-06, 133: 1.8046406979714436e-06, 134: 6.323857056647831e-07, 135: 0.0, 136: 0.02687035978739826, 137: 2.113265956887789e-06, 138: 0.0, 139: 1.2268880365288736e-08, 140: 9.16271144741008e-08, 141: 2.6854718971158224e-06, 142: 5.167781965397462e-06, 143: 1.1515220571420997e-06, 144: 8.436846952494006e-07, 145: 0.0, 146: 0.00014135440728774116, 147: 2.4537760730577472e-08, 148: 2.4037945179865694e-06, 149: 3.6641108583001195e-07, 150: 9.524858913463773e-05, 151: 3.4080223236913156e-08, 152: 1.8403320547933104e-07, 153: 0.0, 154: 0.0, 155: 4.089626788429578e-08, 156: 0.0001652742424942233, 157: 4.089626788429578e-08, 158: 4.792698586965206e-06, 159: 1.151331739012335e-06, 160: 0.0, 161: 2.4042212720527196e-06, 162: 5.842323983470826e-08, 163: 2.529053292567992e-05, 164: 1.7526971950412477e-08, 165: 3.3803819101741307e-07, 166: 4.3671371776444425e-07, 167: 4.498589467272537e-08, 168: 3.1351705266406723e-07, 169: 0.00040220047873007524, 170: 1.2076646755280126e-05, 171: 0.015492407332440322, 172: 8.376867955345824e-06, 173: 0.0036310041038156615, 174: 4.089626788429578e-08, 175: 3.309676536636223e-06, 176: 3.2067729765384276e-07, 177: 3.111037521198216e-07, 178: 1.3712597154786128e-06, 179: 6.134440182644368e-08, 180: 9.112055842871576e-07, 181: 1.8403320547933104e-07, 182: 4.089626788429578e-08, 183: 0.0, 184: 1.2725037854772063e-06, 185: 2.828334869845182e-06, 186: 8.069594875170074e-06, 187: 4.0825673136162185e-07, 188: 1.0395368746413048e-05, 189: 1.2821395685548659e-05, 190: 1.8403320547933104e-07, 191: 0.0, 192: 3.680664109586621e-07, 193: 1.8403320547933104e-07, 194: 4.3451620726611605e-07, 195: 0.0, 196: 9.79246528679504e-07, 197: 5.392921255516175e-07, 198: 0.0016628780885075156, 199: 9.450375984913955e-06, 200: 1.383389514169764e-05, 201: 0.0, 202: 7.655514235000151e-06, 203: 1.6468476377937862e-05, 204: 2.729575812106239e-06, 205: 0.0, 206: 1.6358507153718312e-07, 207: 0.0, 208: 1.8607645913792854e-08, 209: 0.0, 210: 0.0, 211: 2.256933560691282e-06, 212: 8.259734640887314e-07, 213: 0.0004681297730936059, 214: 1.8705660814077714e-06, 215: 0.0, 216: 0.0, 217: 3.1772451130020554e-05, 218: 0.0, 219: 2.453776073057747e-07, 220: 0.0, 221: 4.898257539778154e-08, 222: 5.93316769541078e-07, 223: 1.1271584511988172e-06, 224: 2.9643732800200658e-06, 225: 1.4547386718842358e-07, 226: 3.0672643513523615e-07, 227: 1.5809328699272056e-06, 228: 0.0, 229: 2.810465326785439e-07, 230: 1.5233859786900177e-06, 231: 2.8865793589644363e-06, 232: 1.3245464993391094e-06, 233: 0.0, 234: 0.0, 235: 3.9873861187188394e-08, 236: 8.01595841612901e-06, 237: 9.201660273966552e-08, 238: 1.5156979955809631e-06, 239: 1.8449221399712053e-05, 240: 6.134440182644368e-08, 241: 0.0, 242: 3.4113860859848286e-06, 243: 4.675806628104484e-07, 244: 0.0, 245: 1.8403320547933104e-07, 246: 3.8221640264939854e-05, 247: 6.134440182644368e-08, 248: 2.118816268883605e-06, 249: 3.218483170457865e-06, 250: 2.1706480646280067e-08, 251: 3.939186945855204e-07, 252:

```
Would anybody help me to show a way to print top 10 nodes.

Thanks
```

Comment: Instead of using a simple dict, you can use a Counter. It provides a most_common method to get top n entries. Refer https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 1):

```
# Get a list of key/value pairs from the dictionary.
data = [(k, v) for (k, v) in bt.items()]

# Sort the list by value in reverse order (biggest to smallest)
data.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

# Get the top 10 as a dictionary.
top_10 = { k: v for (k, v) in data[:10] }

print(top_10)
```